# Flutter BLoC and streams for apps that should be always on

Tags: flutter

I'm programming an app that should be always on. According to documentation it should be good to dispose streams to avoid memory leaks. But how to do this in an app that is always on and should be constantly using some streams from BLoC?

Are there any recommendations/patterns for these kinds of apps? Should I be closing and reopening streams?

Answer (score 0):

Disposing of a Stream listener should occur only when it's not needed anymore. One example of this is in a `StatefulWidget`'s state `dispose()` method, i.e. override `dispose()` when you're extending StatefulWidget, cancel the subscription to the stream and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you @kristiyan.mitev for the explanation. The widget is on all the time and after around 48 hours I'm starting to notice performance decline. Should I dispose the widget and re-create it again to dispose stream and re-create it again?

Comment: I am not sure if disposing of the listener and recreating it will have any effect. Maybe it's another part of the code that is causing this decline in performance, but without any specifics it's impossible to tell you something definitive. You could always test it, tho.